# Drawer not opening on swipe after once tapped outside to close

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

Current Behavior

In React navigation 5

Drawer properly opens and closes on openDrawer() and closeDrawer() events, but facing issues while using swipe gesture to open drawer.

Steps to Reproduce:-
1)Open Drawer once
2)Tap outside Drawer and close.
3)Swipe to open drawer. ( Facing problem here, not able to open)

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed all the installation instructions for `react-native-gesture-handler`?

From https://software-mansion.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/getting-started.html :

*"Update your MainActivity.java file:"*

```java
package com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.example;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;  //Add this...
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;  //...and this...
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView; //...and this

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "Example";
  }
//Add this function
  @Override
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
      @Override
      protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
       return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
      }
    };
  }
}
```